# Batch script to list files in directory given by file extension

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'd like to write a simple line to list all the files inside a folder with given extension. Here is what I'd tried:

```
FOR %I IN (.\*) DO IF %~NXI == *.asm  @ECHO %~I
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work!

The problem seems to be with the `*` wildcard because when changed to just:

```
FOR %I IN (.\*) DO IF %~NXI == r_draw16.asm  @ECHO %~I
```

it does work - outputs the `.\r_draw16.asm` as expected!

My question is WHY the solution with wildcard doesn't work and ho to correct it to do the job?

Comment: Well as you're looking for `asm` files, why not just use the extension? `FOR %I IN (.\*) DO @IF /I "%~xI" == ".asm"  ECHO %~I`. In a batch file you would have to double the `%` characters, i.e. `@FOR %%I IN (.\*) DO @IF /I "%%~xI" == ".asm"  ECHO %%~I`. It would however be simpler to use `@FOR %%I IN (.\*.asm) DO @ECHO %%~I`. If you open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, you should see all of the available modifiers.

Comment: `IF` comparison's are string literals unless you are comparing an integer.  There is no form of regular expressions for comparison's with the `IF` command. The `FINDSTR` command does have limited regular expression capability.

Comment: What about `dir *.asm /A-D /B`? Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `dir /?` and read the output help. It would be also good to run once `for /?` and `if /?` and `echo /?` as well as the command `help` to get displayed an (incomplete) list of [Windows commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) explained also by [SS64.com - A-Z index of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@echo off
for %%I in (*.asm) do echo %%I
```